# Having grouped rows in bootstrap Vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to figure out a way to have grouped rows while using `b-table` in bootstrap Vue table. 
By grouped, I mean something like this.

[image]

This is allowed in (https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/grouped-table.html#customizing-header-row).

But I have not been able to find a similar functionality in case of `b-table`. Has anyone done it before? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think not for now in their current documentations, as `b-table` in bootstrapVue component only supports **pagination, filtering, sorting, custom rendering, various style options, events, and asynchronous data.**  but with limited templating

If for custom-table, just use regular `v-for` templating like usual Bootstrap `<table>` in HTML. Or made your reusable custom component e.g `<my-grouped-table :slots="data">`

Comment: I understand. Hey, is this possible to be done? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288939/displaying-multiple-bootstrap-vuejs-tables-based-on-response-from-api)

Comment: I will just answer here instead going here and there. For BootstrapVue to have v-for within `b-table`, i don't think possible yet as there are some complexities to be concerned. I would just build my own-custom-component with my own defined `template` with those accordion collapse and grouping. If this thread is considered answered, kindly marked as answered, cheers thx