# Displaying multiple bootstrap VueJS tables based on response from API

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I am in the process of using bootstrap-vue table. Currently, my entire data resides in one table. Let's assume there are 10 rows in this table, and the first 5 rows contain value `A` in the first column while the next 5 rows contain value `B` in the first column.

What I want is, instead of having a single table containing complete data, I divide this table, so that on my page will appear two tables. The first table would contain all rows with values `A` and the second table would contain all rows with values `B`. In reality, I would have a lot of these unique values, so let's say, if I have 10 such values, I want 10 such individual tables based on these values. Is this possible to do?

Another idea could be, that if above is not possible, can I have collapsible rows? I am not talking about the `More Details` functionality, but rather, when I click on the `A`, all rows with value `A` would appear in the same table each appearing as a row in the table.

I was initially thinking of having rows that can span columns ([Having grouped rows in bootstrap Vue table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285403/having-grouped-rows-in-bootstrap-vue-table/62287757#62287757)) but unfortunately, that is not supported by bootstrap vue-js table yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by utilizing a computed property that splits your array up into groups.

This computed property will return a object, that contains a key which will be the value you're grouping on, and the value will be an array containing all items in that group.

```js
/* Example structure that the computed property will return */
{
  A: [],
  B: [],
  C: []
}
```

You can then use a `v-for` to look each key in the `groupedItems`

```html
<!-- 
  groupedItems is the computed property, containing the structure shown above.
  Will create a new table for each type/key in the `groupedItems` property.
-->
<div v-for="(group, type) in groupedItems">
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="group"><b-table>
</div>
```

---

#### Example snippet:

A fairly basic example, which just display a header of the type and the table underneath.

```js
/* Generate some random example data */
const types = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const items = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  items.push({
    type: types[i % 3],
    id: i + 1,
    random: Math.random()
  })
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    groupedItems() {
      const groups = {};
      
      this.items.forEach(item => {
        if(groups[item.type]) {
          groups[item.type].push(item);
        } else {
          groups[item.type] = [item];
        }
      });

      return groups;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: items,
      fields: ['type', 'id', 'random']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(items, type) in groupedItems">
    <h2>Type: {{ type }}</h2>
    <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
      <template #cell(type)="{ value }">
        Type: {{ value }}
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Example utilizing an [accordion](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#accordion-support)

This example utilizes an accordion, to allow each group to be opened/closed.
Accoridon's only allow one group to be open at a type. If you don't want this , you can remove `accordion="table-accordion"` from the `b-collapse` so multiple can be opened at the same time.

```js
/* Generate some random example data */
const types = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const items = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  items.push({
    type: types[i % 3],
    id: i + 1,
    random: Math.random()
  })
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    groupedItems() {
      const groups = {};

      this.items.forEach(item => {
        if(groups[item.type]) {
          groups[item.type].push(item);
        } else {
          groups[item.type] = [item];
        }
      });

      return groups;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: items,
      fields: ['type', 'id', 'random']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-card no-body class="mb-1" v-for="(group, type) in groupedItems">
    <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-0" role="tab">
      <b-button block v-b-toggle="`accordion-${type}`" variant="primary">
        Type {{ type }}
      </b-button>
    </b-card-header>
    <b-collapse :id="`accordion-${type}`" accordion="table-accordion" role="tabpanel">
      <b-table :fields="fields" :items="group"></b-table>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

---

#### Additional example based on request in comments.

You can easily add another level by doing the same thing again, but nesting it one level deeper.

```js
/* Generate some random example data */
const types = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const items = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  items.push({
    type: types[i % 3],
    group: i % 9,
    id: i + 1,
    random: Math.random()
  })
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    groupedItems() {
      const groups = {};

      this.items.forEach(item => {
        if(!groups[item.type]) groups[item.type] = {};

        if(groups[item.type][item.group]) {
          groups[item.type][item.group].push(item);
        } else {
          groups[item.type][item.group] = [item];
        }
      });

      return groups;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: items,
      fields: ['type', 'id', 'random']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-card no-body class="mb-4" v-for="(groups, type) in groupedItems">
    <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-0" role="tab">
      <b-button block v-b-toggle="`accordion-${type}`" variant="primary">
        Type {{ type }}
      </b-button>
    </b-card-header>
    <b-collapse :id="`accordion-${type}`" visible role="tabpanel">
      <b-card no-body v-for="(items, group) in groups">
        <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-0" role="tab">
          <b-button block v-b-toggle="`accordion-group-${group}`" variant="secondary">
            Type {{ group }}
          </b-button>
        </b-card-header>
        <b-collapse :id="`accordion-group-${group}`"  :accordion="`table-accordion-${type}`" role="tabpanel">
          <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items"></b-table>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-card>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Comment: great. This is what I wanted. Is there any way which will allow me all the tables to be visible by default? They are closed right now by default.

Comment: If you mean in the second example. Remove `accordion="table-accordion"` and add `visible` to the `b-collapse`.

Comment: Great, got it. Thank you so much for the help. Just wanted to ask, can this be further nested as well? Like, under Type A we can have more such accordions? And then under Type B and Type C respectively as well? Let's say, when I click Type A, it presents 3 headings, and clicking either of the heading opens a table finally.

Comment: @JohnDoe I added another snippet with another level.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the help. This is amazing.

Comment: just a small request, do you know how can I make content inside buttons alligned towards left? Currently, it's in center. I looked at a couple of answers online but none seemed to work.

Comment: You can use the class `text-left` which is a bootstrap [text utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-alignment) class.